Unable to start WinNat service
I am unable to start the WinNat service on a Windows Server 2016 host, I get the following:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-service WinNat

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  WinNat             Windows NAT Driver


PS C:\Users\Administrator> start-service WinNat
start-service : Service 'Windows NAT Driver (WinNat)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start
service WinNat on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-service WinNat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

PS C:\Users\Administrator>

Event Viewer says this:
The Windows NAT Driver service failed to start due to the following error: 
Element not found.

I took a look at this similar post, but it did not resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267922/failed-to-start-winnat-service (I was unable to delete all of the keys).
Any help would be appreciated.

I'm sure "." is not a valid computer name.

@paladin I'd agree, but this is not the computers name. I'm not sure where it is getting that information from. Running $env:computername provides the correct computer name.

I do not know why, but this solved my issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807742/remove-netnatstaticmapping-the-requested-operation-is-not-supported-when-tryi
Removing the key in the registry allowed me to start the WinNat service.
